# Why won't my UIButton work?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, storyboard, sharekit

I'm trying to call Sharekit with a UIButton, but when I tap the button running on my device, nothing happens.

This should be the relevant code in my view controller's .h

```
#import "SHK.h"
#import "SHKFacebook.h"    
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CaptureManagerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *upload; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *upload;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

And in my view controller's .m (using code from example here http://gazapps.com/wp/2011/07/17/basic-sharekit-customization)

```
@synthesize upload;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gazapps.com"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Checkout this site"];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
}

-(void)dealloc 
{
   [upload release];
}
```

Besides trying to use a UIButton instead of UIBarButton, I've followed Sharekit's install instructions to the letter. In my storyboard, I CTRL-dragged to the "first responder" and linked up my button to buttonPressed. I'm not getting any warnings or errors in xcode. But nothing happens when I tap the button.

Comment: Put logs in this method and check if it is being called or not ?

Comment: Have u assigned delegate of ur "buttonPressed" method to ur button?? And if so, put break point at method definition and check whether it is called or not..

Comment: You want share to facebook, without action sheet?

Comment: Offtopic: You are using storyboard (and therefore you are only developing for iOS5) and you aren't using ARC? Why?

Comment: Yep, I'd like to skip the actionsheet, and for the moment only share to FB. 

The reason I'm only deving for iOS5 isn't for the sake of storyboard, but because the face-detection I'm using only works in iOS5. But I'm using storyboard because my app needs tons of views and it seemed like a good way to organize them.

Comment: @Goti sorry but could please advise how to go about doing that?

Comment: Aarre...right click on File's owner and drag method to button....

Comment: @Goti I think this might be a storyboard thing - I'm not seeing File's Owner anywhere.

Comment: Uff..yes than try putting breakpoints and check whether method is called or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems fine. The problem is probably within the nib file. Check your connections again.
Are you doing anything else with your `upload` (UIButton) property? You don't need that Outlet at all, if you only want to trigger one `IBAction`.

You could put a breakpoint in your `buttonPressed` method, to see if the connections are setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you should use SHKActionSheet

```
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [EDShareActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];    
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```